# Maven Project: Spring cannot find property file inside src/main/resources using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, maven

Spring cant find my property file (MyPropFile.properties) inside src/main/resources and throws an exception like below

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [file*:/src/main/resources/MyPropFile.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

But if I place MyPropFile.properties at the root of my project (MyProject/MyPropFile.properties)  spring can find it and the programs executes properly.

How do I configure this so that I can place my .properties file inside src/main/resources

this is my namespace

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    ">
```

this is my bean

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:MyPropFile.properties" />
```

Java:

```
@Value("${message.fromfile}")
      private String message;
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Make this entry in your application config file:

```
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 .....
 xsi:schemaLocation="...
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 ....>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:MyPropFile.properties" />
 ....
</beans>
```

and access the message property:

```
@Value("${messageFromfile}")
private String message;
```

Comment: I have updated my question reflecting the changes you suggested sir.
Unfortunately it still cant find the property file
java.io.FileNotFoundException: MyPropFile.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: comment-out the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean definition and try to build and run your app.

Comment: Its only working if MyPropFile.properties is at the root of my project.  I was hoping that it would work even if it is at src/main/resources/MyPropFile.properties

Comment: have you removed `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`?

Comment: Yes I also updated my question to reflect the changes to my bean.
does this method work even if I am running it using my IDE?  Or does this only work when the project is compiled/packaged in a jar?  Coz I am running my the project using Eclipse/STS rightclick-> run as

Comment: error says Spring is looking for `MyPropFile.properties` while you have added `Financials_Constant.properties` to `context:property-placeholder`. do you have `Financials_Constant.properties` inside resources?

Comment: after changing it to MyPropFile.properties it seems to find the property file but retrieves the message is null

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect Maven to copy this to the *target* directory and for the classpath to be set appropriately. I wouldn't expect Maven to search the *source* directory other than at compile time.

Comment: what do you mean?  It runs fine inside eclipse if i put the property file at the root of the  project.  My problem is when I put the property file at src/main/resources which is suppose to be the default resource location for a maven project.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:/MyPropFile.properties</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Without the `classpath:` prefix, the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is attempting to resolve the resource as a file resource, so is looking for it in your current working directory.

Comment: tried it just now but it gives this error. 
By the way Im using Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE
java.io.FileNotFoundException: MyPropFile.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)

Comment: Could you verify that `{project directory}/target/classes/MyPropFile.properties` exists?

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to *@ryanp* solution which is the correct and sanitized way to deal with files resources, which should be under the *classpath* location.

Maven will automagically collect the configured file resources and append them to your runtime *classpath* holder so that resources prefixed with ***classpath:*** can be resolved.

Otherwise, if you find your self stack with Maven not being able to stream file resources, you may hook into Maven's resources configuration and map your files location as follows:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```